# Should I remove co-varying factors before clustering?

Tags: clustering, python, feature-selection, covariance

I have a data set of around 850 factors representing 150 geographical areas. I am looking to cluster these geographical areas, and I am intending to use a K-means clustering algorithm to do this. My exploratory analysis (plotting heatmaps, example below) has suggested there are quite a few of these factors that co-vary. Should I remove these co-varying factors before clustering? If so, what threshold is standard, and is there any standard method for deciding which factor to remove? I am trying to do this in python with scikit, so any pointers in this direction would be helpful.

[image: heatmap of data set]

Answer (score 0):

I would rather try to *weight* them appropriately.

I don't think you can compute the "correct" weights. Just like the scaling they are all equally valid, it is a choice of the user how to weight factors. But of course you should take redundancy into account when weighting factors.

But consider, for example, population and GDP. They are probably highly correlated. You don't want to remove either. However, for data analysis, it is more meaningful to use GDP per capita instead, i.e., normalize and preprocess the data differently.

Furthermore, you *will* have to carefully do the weighting anyway, because clustering - in particular k-means - is *very* sensitive to scaling of variables.